# how do i list all possible directories and paths to subfolders ignoring files

Tags: c#, directory

I want all possible folder paths from the root, ignoring all paths that end with only a file.
getdirectories is not listing every possible path.

for ex:
root : folders   a and b

```
      path a - c
      path a - c - d
      path a - c - x

      path b - e
      path b - e - f
      path b - e - g
```

Comment: have you considered using recursion?

Comment: need need to recurse though each directory.

Comment: What do you mean with "ignoring all paths that will end with only a file"? Does that mean there must be at least two files or should this folder only be included if it has another subdirectory in it?

Comment: i meant that files dont show up in listing, just folders

Answer (score 2):

You need to recursively iterate and visit each folder. See an example in this [MSDN artcile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Directory.GetDirectories() returns all *immediate* children.

You need to make the call recursive.  Pseudocode below - I've no access to computer at the moment.

```
// Output All Leaf Nodes From Root
EnumerateDirectory(@"c:\");

public void EnumerateDirectory(string baseDirectory)
{
    if( Directory.GetDirectories(baseDirectory).Count == 0 )
    {
         // This is an end, leaf node.
         Output("This is a leaf node.");
         return;
    }

    foreach(var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(baseDirectory) )
    {
          EnumerateDirectory(directory);
          return;
    }
}
```

Comment: "No access to a computer with anything more than a browser and notepad."  is more accurate.... sad times, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to write a recursive function. You can just use one of the overloads.

```
oRoot.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: "The weakness in this approach is that if any one of the subdirectories under the specified root causes a DirectoryNotFoundException or UnauthorizedAccessException, the whole method fails and returns no directories" (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx)

Comment: The strengthness in this approach is that it's 1 line of code and could be good enough for whatever he's doing.

Comment: True. However it's not robust and if you run it on one of the recent OS such as Win7 or W2K8 Server your solution is very likely to encounter problems.

Answer (score 1):

This approach addresses the issue mentioned by Strillo on his comment to Nick's answer. It's also more efficient.

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(yourRoot);

foreach (var d in info.EnumerateDirectories("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.FullName);
}
```

Read the Remarks section on [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383573.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of directories to look through and need to skip directories that the user doesn't have access to, your best bet is [EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx):

```
        // LINQ query.
        var dirs = from dir in 
                 Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\", "*",                         SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                   select dir;

        // Show results.
        foreach (var dir in dirs)
        {
            // Do something with the dir
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ListAllDirectories(string root)
{
    DirectoryInfo dr = new DirectoryInfo(root);
                Console.WriteLine(dr.FullName);
                var directories = dr.GetDirectories();
                foreach (var directory in directories)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ListAllDirectories(directory.FullName);

                    }

                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                }
}
```

Catch is for handling Unauthorized Exceptions etc, just to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

*Finally converted my VB.NET version to C#:*

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class DirectoryExtensions
    {
        public static List<DirectoryInfo> GetSubFolders(this DirectoryInfo rootFolder)
        {
            if (rootFolder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Root-Folder must not be null!", "rootFolder");
            }

            List<DirectoryInfo> subFolders = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
            AddSubFoldersRecursively(rootFolder, ref subFolders);
            return subFolders;
        }

        private static void AddSubFoldersRecursively(DirectoryInfo rootFolder, ref List<DirectoryInfo> allFolders)
        {
            try
            {
                allFolders.Add(rootFolder);
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subFolder in rootFolder.GetDirectories())
                {
                    AddSubFoldersRecursively(subFolder, ref allFolders);
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException exUnauthorized)
            {
                // go on 
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exNotFound)
            {
                // go on 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody is interested in a VB.NET version:

```
Public Module DirectoryExtensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function GetSubFolders(ByVal rootFolder As DirectoryInfo) As List(Of DirectoryInfo)
        If rootFolder Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Root-Folder must not be null!", "rootFolder")
        End If

        Dim subFolders As New List(Of DirectoryInfo)
        AddSubFoldersRecursively(rootFolder, subFolders)
        Return subFolders
    End Function

    Private Sub AddSubFoldersRecursively(rootFolder As DirectoryInfo, ByRef allFolders As List(Of DirectoryInfo))
        Try
            allFolders.Add(rootFolder)
            For Each subFolder In rootFolder.GetDirectories
                AddSubFoldersRecursively(subFolder, allFolders)
            Next
       Catch exUnauthorized As UnauthorizedAccessException
           ' go on '
       Catch exNotFound As DirectoryNotFoundException
           ' go on '
       Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
       End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Tested with:

```
Dim result = Me.FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
     Dim rootPath = Me.FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
     Dim rootFolder = New DirectoryInfo(rootPath)
     Dim query = From folder In rootFolder.GetSubFolders()
            Select folder.FullName
     If query.Any Then
          Me.ListBox1.Items.AddRange(query.ToArray)
     End If
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This will take care of the `DirectoryNotFoundException` and `UnauthorizedAccessException`:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetFoldersRecursive(string directory)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    var stack = new Stack<string>();
    stack.Push(directory);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var dir = stack.Pop();

        try
        {
            result.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*.*"));
            foreach (string dn in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                stack.Push(dn);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that this will likely not be as performant as other methods due to the `try`/`catch` block.

**Disclaimer: I didn't write this code originally (found it on SO!), I've only modified it to fit the need.*